# UR10 in self-destruction mode for certain trajectories

Tags: python, ros-noetic, trajectory

I am using a UR10 robot with official drivers with ROS1 (noetic) and python.

I coded a trajectory generator that creates waypoints.
These are also used by a trajectory server and sent to the robot.
The SAME waypoints are visualized as a sanity-check, to ensure that the trajectory is valid.

For some trajectories, the robot instead of going to the first waypoint, starts to rotate the TCP around the z-axis and starts an uncontrolled upwards movement.
This **self-destruct movement** even crashes into the world model (which has collision checks!) - So planning a movement that crashes into the world is normally impossible. But for this error movement, crashes are possible.

The code used for trajectory execution is very basic:

```
(plan, fraction) = self.move_group.compute_cartesian_path(
            waypoints, 0.1, 0)  # eef_step, jump_threshold

move_succeeded = self.move_group.execute(plan, wait=True)
```

In the following, the easy (always working) trajectory and the self-destruct trajectory are visualized.
The frame shown is the TCP frame of the UR10 robot.

easy trajectory:
pickup_s([0.4 0.8 0.2])_g([1.  0.6 0. ])
[image: valid movement 1]

self-destructs-trajectory:
pickup_s([1.2 0.5 0.2])_g([1.  0.6 0. ])
[image: causes uncontrolled motion]

Note for the second one, the y-axis points towards the front, so to reach the first point, a z rotation around 180 degrees is necessary. I suspect this is not possible by some joint limits.
I do not see why an uncontrolled upward motion without crash detection can be caused.

Normally, for some trajectories the

```
(plan, fraction) = self.move_group.compute_cartesian_path(
            waypoints, 0.1, 0)  # eef_step, jump_threshold
```

section fails.
But i this can find a path, the found path should never crash the collision-enabled geometries in my URDF.
If I change the default lower URDF limit 1.3 (magic number?) of the wrist_1_joint to -pi

```
    <!-- <limit effort="54.0" lower="1.3" upper="6.28" velocity="3.2"/> -->
    <limit effort="54.0" lower="-3.14" upper="6.28" velocity="3.2"/>
```

And then execute the trajectory, it works without the uncontrolled upward motion.

In [this Youtube-video](https://youtu.be/9TJ0gf721Y8), I summed up the crashes

First Old limits, easy-trajectory, self-destructs-trajectory (with crash)
Then rotation of the wrist-1-joint by 360deg, adaption of the joint limits
Then again easy-trajectory, self-destructs-trajectory (without crash)